# Escaping single quotes in MSSQL

Tags: sql, node.js

I'm making an Insert query to add a row to a table.

I'm currently using a library called `sqlstring` : `SqlString.escape(str);`

[npm package here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlstring)

When `str` has a single quote in it, like `"123'456"`, the above function outputs this: `"123\'456"`. My mssql server doesn't seem to like that.

```
{
  "info": {
    "name": "ERROR",
    "event": "errorMessage",
    "number": 105,
    "state": 1,
    "class": 15,
    "message": "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.",
    "serverName": "CALLIOPE",
    "procName": "",
    "lineNumber": 3
  }
}
```

Wondering if you guys have any advice about how I can escape this string properly for mssql

Comment: Don't use escaping. Use parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the library i was using above is for MySql mainly.
For MSSQL, there's [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsqlstring) instead, although that has its own problem -- escaping double quotes, `"` (I'm pretty sure the problem is that mssql doesn't NEED any double-quote escaping, so it's just unecessary)